# curl in bash script vs curl one liner

Tags: bash, curl

This code ouputs a http status of 000 - which seems to indicate something didn't connect properly but when I do this curl outside of the bash script it works fine and produces a 200 so something with this code is off... any guidance?

```
#!/bin/bash

URLs=$(< test.txt | grep Url | awk -F\  ' { print $2 } ')
# printf "Preparing to check $URLs \n"
for line in $URLs
    do curl  -L -s -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" $line
done
```

http://beerpla.net/2010/06/10/how-to-display-just-the-http-response-code-in-cli-curl/

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop to iterate over the URLs; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, or write the URLs to a `curl` config file to be loaded with the `--config` option.

Comment: The value of `$URLs` probably contain meta-characters or spaces that bash shell expands into something else. You may need to escape these meta-characters and replace spaces with `%20`.

Comment: BTW, what does your actual file format look like? Is the word "Url" always at the beginning of the line for the lines you care about? Are those URLs potentially followed by other data on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

your script works on my vt.

I added in a couple of debugging lines, this may help you to see where any metacharacters are getting in, as I would have to agree with the posted coments.

I've output lines in the for to a file which is then printed out with `od`.
I have amended the curl line to grab the last line, just to get the response code.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n > $HOME/Desktop/urltstfile # truncate urltstfile

URLs=$(cat testurl.txt | grep Url | awk -F\  ' { print $2 } ')

# printf "Preparing to check $URLs \n"

for line in $URLs
    do echo $line >> $HOME/Desktop/urltstfile;
       echo line:$line:

     curl  -IL -s -w "%{http_code}\n" $line | tail -1
done

od -c $HOME/Desktop/urltstfile

#do curl  -L -s -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" "$line\n"
```

Comment: `echo -n` is an extension POSIX does not mandate (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html). Merely `> "$HOME/Desktop/urltstfile"` will suffice, but you're much better off leaving the file descriptor open: `exec 3>"$HOME/Desktop/urltstfile"` will both truncate and the file and let you redirect things to it with `>&3`, which doesn't require reopening the file and is thus much faster than using `>>"$HOME/Desktop/urltstfile"` inside your loop.

Comment: Also, `echo $line` is buggy; use `echo "$line"` to avoid expanding globs and converting runs of characters found in IFS  (ie. tabs) to a single space each -- or, even better, `printf '%s\n' "$line"`, which will behave correctly in cases where `echo`'s behavior is ambiguously specified.

Comment: ...and see http://shellcheck.net/ for a bunch of automated advice about fixing up missing quoting &c.

Comment: Also -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor (as chepner also points out in a comment on the question, the correct way to loop over lines in a file is given in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: What's a "vt" please?